# How to get the elements of an array returned by a service in Angular 2?

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, primeng

I'm learning Angular 2 + PrimeNG and I'm studying this quick start project: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng-quickstart

It's a CRUD and works very well. All the data is being shown in a table in my browser. Great!

Now I'm trying to change the code a little bit. All works fine, except my stupid code.

```
export class AppComponent {

    displayDialog: boolean;

    car: Car = new PrimeCar();

    selectedCar: Car;

    newCar: boolean;

    cars: Car[];

    constructor(private carService: CarService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.carService.getCarsMedium().then(cars => this.cars = cars);

        //THIS IS MY CODE:
        console.log(this.cars);            
        for (let entry of this.cars) {
            console.log(entry);
        }
    }
```

The first `console.log` gives me an `undefined` message. Then the `for` breaks the application.

So I'm basically trying to show in the console the same data that is shown in the browser. Someone could help me with that?

Thanks! =)

Comment: Read http://blog.ninja-squad.com/2015/05/28/angularjs-promises/. It's about AngularJS 1, but the principle of promises and asynchronous programming is the same. The service doesn't **return** cars. It returns a promise of cars. The cars will only be available **later**, inside the callback function passed to then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the code that depends on the observable result inside `then(...)`, otherwise the code will be executed before the value is available

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.carService.getCarsMedium().then(cars => {
        this.cars = cars
        //THIS IS MY CODE:
        console.log(this.cars);            
        for (let entry of this.cars) {
            console.log(entry);
        }
    });

}
```